# PHP cast from string to int error

Tags: php

Hi when trying to cast from a string to int using `int()` I get the following error:

> Call to undefined function int()

Why would this be?

`intval()` works just fine but I cannot use `int()` for some reason.

Comment: there is no such function in PHP?

Answer (score 10):

There is no `int` function; you must use proper typecasting syntax for this:

```
$b = (int) $a;
```

Or:

```
settype($a, 'int');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function int($string) {
   return (int) $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$intVar = (int)$var;
```

If PHP is telling you that int() isn't a function, then it probably isn't.